# Why is the 8085 microprocessor not provided with a G register?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I know that there are 7 general purpose registers( A,B,C,D,E,H and L). I am told that F is missing as F is said to be corresponding to flag register but I am not able to understand why they left out G. This has nothing to do with anything technical just a curiosity.

Comment: Probably because G looks like C.  Would avoid confusion on handwritten code.

Comment: it looks like the 8-bit registers are paired ... A&flags, BC, DE ... FG would also be a pair, but F is paired with A, so no room for G

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia's [Intel 8085](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8085) article suggests to me that H and L are not the same type of register. Instead H and L appear to refer to the High and Low bytes of the 16-bit indirect address.

```
Main registers
A   Flags   Program Status Word
B   C
D   E
H   L       (indirect address)
```

Comment: Yes thanks. I think it makes quite a lot of sense to leave G in this case.

Comment: ...and there are a few other instructions that use H and L together as if they were a single 16-bit register, such as LHLD and SHLD.